# Swift 2.1: How do you produce a set from an array?

Tags: arrays, set, swift2

**Scenario:**
An array of strings, many are duplicated.

**Goal:**
Produce a UNIQUE array of strings.

**Modus Operandi:**
I was thinking of converting the array to a set of strings which become unique; from which to generate a new array of unique strings.

**Question:** How does one convert a Swift array into a Swift Set?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624331

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let nonUniqueArray = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A"]
let uniqueArray = Array(Set(nonUniqueArray))
print(uniqueArray)
```

produces

```
["C", "B", "A"]
```

Swift 2.2 produces exactly the same result as well.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried `let myset = Set(myarray)` ?