# Changing the size of an array inside of in for-in loop

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I was presented this problem where I need to find matching numbers in a given array (socks) and print out how many socks found inside that array. Here is my code:

```
let numberOfSocks = 9
let socksArray = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10]

func findSocks(numberOfSocks: Int, array: [Int]) {

    var arr = array
    var uniqueSocks = Array(Set(array))
    var matchedPairs = 0
    var sockCounter = 0

    for i in 0..<uniqueSocks.count { // After the search, remove the element at index
        sockCounter = 0
        for j in 0..<arr.count {
            if uniqueSocks[i] == arr[j] {
                sockCounter += 1 
                if sockCounter % 2 == 0 {
                    matchedPairs += 1
                    sockCounter = 0
                }
            }    
        }
    }
    print(matchedPairs)
}    
findSocks(numberOfSocks: numberOfSocks, array: socksArray)
```

Firstly, I have removed all the duplicates in the array so it gives me a list unique socks that I need to search for. However, I wanted to optimize this algorithm by remove the sock that I have already searched for, I have tried `arr.remove(at:)` but It gave me an out of bound, I have a feeling that `arr.count` is not updated correctly. Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: It may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624331/unique-values-of-array-in-swift

Comment: Removing element from collection while looping thru it is not ideal. You can try different approach with Dictionary data structure with better time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're overthinking the problem, focusing on small details rather than the big picture. What you want to end up with is essentially a dictionary where the keys are the unique values in the array, and the values are the number of times those values appear in the array. So start with your dictionary:

```
var counts = [Int : Int]()
```

There's no need for your `arr` and `numberOfSocks` variables. Instead of the latter, just use `socksArray.count`, which clearly will always be in sync with the true size of the array.

Now loop through your socks. For each sock value, increment its count in the `counts` dictionary or, if it's not already in the dictionary, add it and give it a count of `1`.

```
for sock in socks {
    if !counts.contains(sock) {
        counts[sock] = 1
    } else {
        counts[sock] = counts[sock] + 1
    }
}
```

There are more concise ways to do this, but I think that this one is the easiest to read.